# python mechanize Http error 100

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I am having trouble logging in my Microsoft account using python mechanize utility. user-name and password are working fine. Problem comes when submitting the form, I get an interim response page with title: "**continue**" . and URL: **some interim_URL**.

Question is how do I move to my intended URL? **br.open("intended_URL")** doesn’t work at all.

Answer (score 0):

First verify if the login is being done by checking the redirected link with 
print br.geturl()
If it is logging in and you're have an http error in your console use exceptions for the http error which will redirect you to your page